# Can't get strong parameters & POST w. CURL to work (Ruby on Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, curl, strong-parameters

I'm having some trouble passing an array of hashes as an param when doing a post with CURL to create a resource for my API (coded in RoR).

I have the following JSON, which I am trying to use as a guide for my POST body:

```
{
  status: 200,
  show: {
    id: 2,
    creator_id: 2,
    venue_id: 2,
    name: "Rock Rumble",
    description: "Another fake event",
    created_at: "2016-02-25T00:21:36.343Z",
    updated_at: "2016-02-25T00:21:36.812Z"
  },
  artists: [{
    id: 5,
    name: "Finntroll",
    created_at: "2016-02-25T00:21:36.462Z",
    updated_at: "2016-02-25T00:21:36.462Z"
  }, {
    id: 6,
    name: "Moonsorrow",
    created_at: "2016-02-25T00:21:36.474Z",
    updated_at: "2016-02-25T00:21:36.474Z"
  }, {
    id: 7,
    name: "Amon Amarth",
    created_at: "2016-02-25T00:21:36.486Z",
    updated_at: "2016-02-25T00:21:36.486Z"
  }, {
    id: 8,
    name: "Satyricon",
    created_at: "2016-02-25T00:21:36.498Z",
    updated_at: "2016-02-25T00:21:36.498Z"
  }],
  showURL: "/api/shows/2",
  venueURL: "/api/venues/2"
}
```

My Show.rb file looks like this:

```
belongs_to :creator
belongs_to :venue
has_many :setlists
has_many :artists, :through => :setlists
validates :name,        presence: true
validates :description, presence: true
```

And Setlist like this:

```
class Setlist < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :artist
belongs_to :show
end
```

And finally artist like this:

```
class Artist < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :setlists
has_many :shows, :through=> :setlists
validates   :name,                      presence: true
end
```

Right now my Api::ShowsController is like

```
def create
    @show = Show.new(show_params.except[:artists])        
    #If there are any artists to be saved with this show
    if show_params[:artists].present?
        #loop through artists, create artist
    else
...
   end
end
...
#Validation of params
private
def show_params
params.require(:show).permit(:name, :description, artists: [:name])
end
```

I can make a post without the artists, but I wanna do something like:

```
    curl \
-H "Accept: application/json" \
-H "Content-type: application/json" \
-X POST \
-d '{"name":"test", "description":"testing post to create", "artists":[{"name":"hey"}] }' \
https://[username].c9users.io/api/shows.json
```

So, how do I permit a nestled prop., and include a array with hashs in them representing artists in my POST body? What am I doing wrong?

As it is, show_params[:artists].present? === FALSE.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. I like how detailed your question is :) - so my immediate question would be: what do you get for `puts params.inspect` ? ie what is the full set of params that are coming through? we can then go step by step from there. (Note: because you're new I should say, you should edit your question and put any code there, rather than replying as a comment - because code-formatting in comments is truly awful :P )

Comment: That said, I think I can already spot an issue, your data is: `-d '{"name":"test", "description":"testing post to create", "artists":[{"name":"hey"}] }'` but your code says you need to require `:show` -> there's no show in the above data, perhaps it should be: `-d '{show: {"name":"test", "description":"testing post to create", "artists":[{"name":"hey"}] }}'` or something???

Comment: That just gave me a parse error, it worked for name & description without spec. show in the post data, thx tho^^

Comment: Where do I put the params inspect snippet in my code? Is it some kinda debug thing?

Comment: just put it at the beginning of your "create" method... `puts` is a printing method that will go to stdout (so if you're watching in the window that you're running the rails server, it will show up there). and `inspect` is a good way of showing the internal details of a complicated structure.

Comment: Hm, I tried that & did another post, nothing showed up in the console though.. I don't get it lol.

Comment: It can sometimes be hard to find. Try adding `puts '*******'` (make it a whole line of asterisks... so that it's easy to spot :) Also make sure it's the very first line in create or you'll hit the error first and won't ever get to the puts line. If it still doesn't show up... you might not be hitting the controller-action you think you're hitting...

Answer (score 0):

Can you try wrapping your json representation in request body with `show` key? Since you're doing `params.require(:show)`, keys in `permit` should be wrapped by the key specified by `require`.

Like:

```
{"show":{"name":"test", "description":"testing post to create", "artists":[{"name":"hey"}]}}
```